# Ubuntu 18 LTS and an LG Monitor with a built-in KVM

Tags: monitor, kvm-virtualization, thunderbolt

I have a LG Electronics UM95 34UM95-P 34 Monitor which has a built in KVM switch. I am running Ubuntu 18 LTS on an MSI GS 65 Stealth that has a USB-C (Thunderbolt-3 port).

My monitor is a old, and supports Thunderbolt-2 so I am using an Apple USB-C -> Thunderbolt-2 adapter. This is so I can connect my monitor to the laptop.

I dual-boot Windows 10 on my laptop and this setup works really well on Windows.
When I boot into Ubuntu, things get a little strange. Often times only my keyboard works for a couple of minutes & then it stops working. My mouse (connected to the same KVM) never works.

Any thoughts on how I can diagnose this further ?

```
/:  Bus 08.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/1p, 5000M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 5000M
        |__ Port 3: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 5000M
            |__ Port 4: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 5000M
/:  Bus 07.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/1p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/2p, 12M
            |__ Port 2: Dev 5, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
            |__ Port 2: Dev 5, If 2, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
            |__ Port 2: Dev 5, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
        |__ Port 2: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=ti_usb_3410_5052, 12M
        |__ Port 3: Dev 6, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
            |__ Port 4: Dev 10, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
            |__ Port 2: Dev 8, If 0, Class=Communications, Driver=cdc_acm, 12M
            |__ Port 2: Dev 8, If 1, Class=CDC Data, Driver=cdc_acm, 12M
            |__ Port 3: Dev 9, If 2, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 480M
            |__ Port 3: Dev 9, If 0, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 480M
            |__ Port 3: Dev 9, If 1, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 480M
        |__ Port 4: Dev 7, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
/:  Bus 06.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/2p, 10000M
/:  Bus 05.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/2p, 480M
/:  Bus 04.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 10000M
/:  Bus 03.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/2p, 480M
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/8p, 10000M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/16p, 480M
    |__ Port 7: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
    |__ Port 7: Dev 2, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
    |__ Port 11: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
    |__ Port 11: Dev 3, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
    |__ Port 14: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
    |__ Port 14: Dev 4, If 1, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
```

This is what `lsusb -t` tells me.

The monitor on its own works well, and some of the *other* USB peripherals connected to the monitor work as expected. My Keyboard and mouse on the other hand, are very sketchy.